# Cannot read property 'firestore' of null when trying to initialize firebase in nuxt app

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I am trying to use Firebase and Firestore in my nuxt application. I have done everything according to the documentation, but something seems to be wrong.
Obviously, `if (!firebase.apps.length)` evaluates to `false`, so `app` stays `null`, but I'm not initializing firebase from anywhere else, so this shouldn't happen

plugins/firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import firestore from "firebase/firestore"; //linter says that firestore is declared but never read, which is weird, since it is.
const firebaseConfig = {
 //config data of my project (not sure if I can share them, so I don't)
};
let app = null;
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export const db = app.firestore();
```

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: ["~/plugins/firebase.js"],
```

layouts/default.vue

```
<script>
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
</script>
```

Comment: If you `console.log(firebase.apps)` what does it show?

Comment: It shows a list with one FirebaseAppImpl object

Comment: Please update your question to show exactly what you've done, and what the output is. It also would help if you take some additional debugging steps yourself, such as logging `firebase.apps.length`, `!firebase.apps.length`, and other things you can think of.